# Typescript + ES6 Proxy

Tags: typescript

ES6 Proxy.apply method serves a way to use classes without a "new" keyword.

But on TypeScript, it gives an error "Value of type 'typeof ClassName' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?".

Is there any way to prevent TypeScript errors?

Here is the simple example of it;

```
class ClassName {
  constructor(anyThing?: any) {
    if (anyThing) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}

// ES6 Proxy
const CustomName = new Proxy(ClassName, {
  apply: (Target, _thisArg, argumentsList) => {
    return new Target(...argumentsList);
  }
});

// Test ---------
new ClassName("test"); // return ClassName { }

// No error
new CustomName("test"); // return ClassName { }

// Javascript: no error
// TypeScript: error => Value of type 'typeof ClassName' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
CustomName("test"); // return ClassName { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is not able to understand what your apply function does to the class. You will need to augment the type.

Solution ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=25#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QHJgLYFNoG8CwAoa0wA9gHYQAuATgK7DlGUAUYJAngCoAWAliQOYB%20AFzQWrAJRY8BAtwBm0Zmy68%20knPhkEA9NugARItAhF05Hv2kyAvldu57eXdACiAZQBs0AAqUiAD1Y8YjJyOGoKU2R0aABeaBI0AHcfP0DGeEgIaLQAGilNMAAHIpBWEUZ2MEo%20NHJ8gH1zbggAQRr86r5qdBJyCAAZFvJJWIA%20Aq1KOupKEgTk6CqausYAOg2unrQ%20weHxAG47PGtJSGhyViK0IgVMpFQMADJFRlGJ%20%20zHw7w8EDroLwKCxgGgRJ8ckdcHggeQQRh4okUhDHm8obD4XEFsiIvQUDk0TDQpj4rBcVFUYcgA))

```
class ClassName {
  constructor(anyThing?: any) {
    if (anyThing) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}

// ES6 Proxy
const CustomName = new Proxy(ClassName, {
  apply: (Target, _thisArg, argumentsList) => {
    return new Target(...argumentsList);
  },
  get: () => { ... }, // Implement static method(s)
}) as typeof ClassName & (() => ClassName) & { staticMethod(): CustomName };

let instance: ClassName;

instance = new ClassName();
instance = new CustomName();
instance = CustomName();
instance = CustomName.staticMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice trick to teach TypeScript, that it's a callable.

Can it refer to a function or a static method?

Comment: I have added a static method type definition. To do class method you need another proxy for the class instance.

Comment: I didn't mean that way.
I mean as a static create( ) method return new ClassName( ).
And cast CustomName as a create() method.

- If a static method not available cast, at least a function.

Comment: Can you show how would you like to use the function? I don’t understand it.

Comment: I added on next answer. Of course, It can't refer to the constructor method.

Answer (score 0):

Make Proxy callable with Target's static method

```
class ClassName {
  constructor(anyThing?: any) {
    if (anyThing) {
      // Do something
    }
  }

  // Forge
  static forge (anyThing?: any) {
    return new ClassName(anyThing);
  }
}

// ES6 Proxy
const CustomName = new Proxy(ClassName, {
  apply: (Target, _thisArg, argumentsList) => {
    return new Target(...argumentsList);
  }
}) as typeof ClassName & typeof ClassName.forge;

let instance: ClassName;

instance = new ClassName();
instance = new CustomName();
instance = CustomName();
```

Comment: This is totally valid TS & JS. No error there. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=8&pln=21&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QHJgLYFNoG8CwAoa0wA9gHYQAuATgK7DlGUAUYJAngCoAWAliQOYB+AFzQWrAJRY8BAtwBm0Zmy68+knPhkEA9NugARItAhF05Hv2kyAvldu4ru6ADEGfNFYphy3YNDluGEocFoIiYupWBJRo5NSUJNAkaADucAgQyOjBKvziANx2ePZ4TgCiAMoAbNAACpREAB6seMRk5HDUFKZZGAC8Sal1Dc2M8JCZqGgANFKaYAAOCyCsIozsYJTu5LMA+ubcEACCW7ObfNToJOQQADKH5JJ9AHxzWjFxCYNpG1uxjAA6IHnS5oa53B4FIq4aySSDQcisBZoIgKcZIKbQABkCKRKLRGV6AICf3y0CcsBYAHIOjE5GhKIRSBQaHQGHg8LAuvQUESSe5GOIObgQLFoLwvCRgGgROjJuhCg5cBLyCxpdABsk0nLeoLFSq1f1vp1urypnq8AapUauabdQUgA